# CLIPS Printout Number Of Times Rule Fired

Tags: clips

I have the following CLIPS construct below and I'm interested in tallying up how many times a particular rule fired so the output will be a series of the rules fired followed by their count (see picture for example). [image: CLIPS Output]
So it would be all those rules followed by:

temperature: (times fired) seconds
pressure: (times fired) seconds

```
(deftemplate oil-measure
  (slot utc-time (type STRING))
  (slot temperature (type INTEGER))
  (slot pressure (type INTEGER)))

(defrule oil-is-hot
  (oil-measure (temperature ?temp) (utc-time ?time))
  (test (> ?temp 32))
  =>
  (printout t ?time tab "temperature:" tab ?temp crlf))

(defrule pressure-is-high
  (oil-measure (pressure ?press&:(> ?press 0)) (utc-time ?time))
  =>
  (printout t ?time tab "pressure:" tab ?press crlf))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store counters in global variables and increase them accordingly.

```
(defglobal ?*hot-oil-times* = 0)

(defrule oil-is-hot
  (oil-measure (temperature ?temp) (utc-time ?time))
  (test (> ?temp 32))
  =>
  (bind ?*hot-oil-times* (+ ?*hot-oil-times* 1))
  (printout t ?time tab "temperature:" tab ?*hot-oil-times* tab ?temp crlf))
```

Comment: Awesome! Included updated code for those that want to follow. Does printout always expect a new construct? Trying to do something like this for the final part. https://imgur.com/a/8CBLpkx

Answer (score 0):

Code incorporating noxdafox's solution:

```
(defglobal ?*hot-oil-times* = 0)
(defglobal ?*high-pressure-times* = 0)

(deftemplate oil-measure
  (slot utc-time (type STRING))
  (slot temperature (type INTEGER))
  (slot pressure (type INTEGER)))

(defrule oil-is-hot
  (oil-measure (temperature ?temp) (utc-time ?time))
  (test (> ?temp 32))
  => 
  (bind ?*hot-oil-times* (+ ?*hot-oil-times* 1))
  (printout t ?time tab "temperature:" tab ?*hot-oil-times* tab ?temp crlf))

(defrule pressure-is-high
  (oil-measure (pressure ?press&:(> ?press 0)) (utc-time ?time))
  =>
  (bind ?*high-pressure-times* (+ ?*high-pressure-times* 1))
  (printout t ?time tab "pressure:" tab ?*high-pressure-times* tab ?press crlf))
```